# how can I get package libz.so.1?

Tags: shared-library

I'm trying to make a Minecraft bedrock edition server and I can't make it work cause of a library called `libz.so.1`. The following error pops up *'cannot open shared library libz.so.1'*.

I have tried installing and updating `zlib1g` but it made no difference.

Answer (score 6):

You need the development libraries for `zlib1g`, not just the runtime environment.

`sudo apt install zlib1g-dev` will install the underlying development libraries that your compiler is trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

Installing the `lib64z1` package solved it for me: `sudo apt install lib64z1`.

---

#### Backstory:

While using a Raspberry Pi OS VM and trying to connect it to GitHub Actions, the library `libz.so.1` was missing.
This error appeared when I ran the `config.sh` script, more specifically when this script ran `ldd ./bin/libSystem.IO.Compression.Native.so`.

I updated both `zlib1g` and `zlib1g-dev` with no improvements.

I then noticed that the only `libz.so.1` library installed was 32 bits by doing `sudo find / -name libz.so.1*`, that returned these 2 file locations:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (this one is a symbolic link to the one above)
```

and analysing this library with `file /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11` returned:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11: ELF 32-bit ...
```

Now that I've found that I was missing the 64-bit version of this library, searching for a package with it was done on the debian packages website: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye&arch=i386&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libz.so.1 which shows that `lib64z1` has the library we want on the 64 bits library directory: `/usr/lib64/libz.so.1`.

I've also confirmed this package exists on the Ubuntu package repository: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lib64z1